# Writing GeoPandas to_CSV using huge amounts of RAM

Tags: pandas, csv, geopandas

I have a csv file of ~500Mb that I load via pandas and convert to geoPandas.

```
thisData = pd.read_csv(myFile1.csv, encoding='utf-8').fillna(0)
thisData['geometry'] = thisData['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
thisData.crs = 'epsg:4326'
```

When that's done it uses 10% of my computer's memory for 210,134 lines and 14 columns.  The data are either columns of ints or strings, and there are empty cells.

Then I filter out some of the data to 195,209 lines.

Now I just want to write that reduced file to my drive

```
thisData.to_csv(myFile2.csv, sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

When I do this, the memory usage quickly climbs to 99% of 32GB and never finishes.  I've worked with many larger files and never had this problem, so there is probably some feature of this data that is causing a problem.  I tried not setting `NaN->0` thinking that it was a problem of mixed dtypes, but I get the same problem.

So now it just threw `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 21.3 GiB for an array with shape (1, 10000) and data type <U572360`  but clearly that shouldn't be necessary for a dataframe of this size, let alone a chunk of this size.

Does anybody with experience writing geopandas files to csv have any hints as to what is causing this memory explosion?

Comment: Are you trying to save the geometry object in a column of the CSV? to_csv is not a GeoDataFrame method, but is simply the pandas.DataFrame method showing up through inheritance. Is there a reason why you don't want to use a more conventional spatial format like GeoJSON or shapefile using the geopandas [`GeoDataFrame.to_file`](https://geopandas.org/io.html#writing-spatial-data)?

Comment: Yes, only some of the processing of these files uses the geometry, a lot of it is just ordinary pandas operations, so it's more convenient to save as csv.

Comment: Also note that I was able to quickly save a pickle file of the GeoDataframe, which is only ~200Mb.  So the problem really is some kind of incompatibility with the pandas csv writer.

Comment: Oh it definitely is - CSV is not a good format for spatial objects. So if _any_ of the operations use the spatial data, I'd recommend saving as a valid spatial format, or if temporary storage is all you need, then a pickle. CSV is a text-only format, so saving any object columns is necessarily going to involve saving the spatial objects as string. This isn't a supported feature of geopandas or pandas, so there's no reason why this _should_ work.

Comment: You could of course use wkt to dump the objects back to a string before saving... `pd.DataFrame(thisData.assign(geometry=thisData.geometry.apply(wkt.dumps))).to_csv(...)`.

Comment: Yes, for temporary purposes a pickle is fine, but to load the data into our database, they have to be strings anyway, and csv is universally supported.  I've done this hundreds of times with other data, so it's not a problem with the geometry objects per se.  It could be a problem with these polygons not be well-formed, or some other data not being well-formed, but I don't know what the likely culprits are.

Comment: The fact that it's trying to coerce the column data type to `<U572360` suggests to me that `df.to_csv` is trying to build a fixed-width string array where each entry the length of the most complex shape. I'd give applying wkt.dumps first a try.

Comment: Yeah, the `wkt.dumps` trick worked.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it as such